# Validating a form

Tags: jquery, validation

The phone number is mandatory in all forms.
- If I have a single form and I click on validate then there will be the error message : "Please enter a phone number ." The form is not submitted .
- If I have two or more forms and I click on it then here will validate tjrs error messages , BUT I need only fill one mandatory field for other forms are submitted and that without their mandatory fields are taken into account.

So what's the pb ?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QmfKEsZSo8vsKcA1k4V8?p=preview)

```
$("#createForms").on("click", function(){
    createForms();
});
```

Comment: Just to confirm are you trying to set it up that each form needs its own validation, that just because the first field has a number does not mean that the second one doesnt need?

Comment: @WhyEnBe i  trying to set it up that each form needs its own validation

Comment: just intercept the submit event and do your stuff there (use .preventDefault()) to cancel the submit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code (in plunker) is that you are adding error messages in the wrong way.
Try removing this from your code:

```
messages: {
        required: "Veuillez saisir un numéro de téléphone",
        digits:"Veuillez saisir des chiffres"
        }
```

See the Jquery [Docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) for the correct way to add this message.

I am having difficulty accessing your plunker to give you more information. It would be helpful if you could post the code to your question.